# Code not returning expected results

Tags: php, arrays

There is `$sFactorGrades` which I need to retrieve the 0th element from based on the `GradeID` and the `CommutatorID`, which is the 1st and 2nd element in the array respectively.

The `GradeID` and the `CommutatorID` is passed as parameters to the function.

The code that I have written is not returning the value which I know is present.

Any recommendations are welcome.

Here is my code:

```
function getMaximumSFactor($commuatorID, $gradeID) {
    $sFactorGrades = populateSFactorGrades();
    $arraySize = count($sFactorGrades);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $arraySize; $i++) {
        if (intval($sFactorGrades[i][1]) == $commuatorID && intval($sFactorGrades[i][2]) == $gradeID) {
            return $sFactorGrades[i][0];
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my data:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => Maximum S Factor
        [1] => Commutator ID
        [2] => Grade ID
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [0] => 0.6
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 2
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [0] => 0.6
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 3
    )
    [3] => Array (
        [0] => 0.6
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 4
    )
)
```

Here is my result:
    `0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you return too early. When your code encounters a `return` statement, it stops the iteration. You need to move the `return` statement outside the loop to prevent this from happening.

```
function getMaximumSFactor($commuatorID, $gradeID) {
    $sFactorGrades = populateSFactorGrades();
    $arraySize = count($sFactorGrades);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $arraySize; $i++) {
        if (intval($sFactorGrades[$i][1]) == $commuatorID && 
            intval($sFactorGrades[$i][2]) == $gradeID) {
            return $sFactorGrades[$i][0];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If your code reached the last `return`, then it means that the `if` condition was never satisfied. For `getMaximumSFactor (1, 2)`, this should return `0.2`.

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/155088)

Comment: makes total sense. Thanks for your answer and the demo.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the reason for your loop always returning `0` is that you're passing `i` as the incrementing variable, and not the correct one: `$i`. Typos can be devastating... If it still doesn't work, feel free to update your post.

Edit: A tip is to insert this at the top of your page while in development stage:

```
ini_set('display_errors','On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

In this case, it should give an `undefined index` error or similar.

Comment: That's not really the problem here, though.

Comment: It was the first and most obvious reason I saw why such an IF statement would never return true.

Answer (score 1):

`$sFactorGrades[i]` need to be `$sFactorGrades[$i]`. 
Also it worth to use `foreach()` instead of normal `for()`. 
But thats not all. You need to check all values in array before returning result:

```
function getMaximumSFactor($commuatorID, $gradeID) {
  $sFactorGrades = populateSFactorGrades();
  foreach($sFactorGrades as $key=>$value){
    if (intval($value[1]) == $commuatorID && intval($value[2]) == $gradeID) {
        return $value[0];
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, wish I could accept more than one answer. +1